# Counting beans with ReactiveCocoa 4 and an NSButton

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I have the following:

- Two interesting classes: a `ViewController` and a `ViewModel`
- A button `nsButtonMorePlease:NSButton` in the `view` of `ViewController`
- A text box `nsTextView:NSTextView` in the `view` as well

I want the following behavior:

- When you launch the program, the "count" starts at 0 and is displayed in the text box `nsTextView`
- When you press the button `nsButtonMorePlease`, the count is incremented by `1` and the updated count is reflected in the `nsTextView`

I would like to ensure:

- I use `ReactiveCocoa 4` (that's the point kind of)
- The model class contains `numberOfBeans: MutableProperty<Int>` starting at `0`
- The design is purely functional or close to it - that is (if I understand the term), every link in the chain mapping the event of mouse click to the `MutableProperty` of `numberOfBeans` to responding to it in the text view, is all without side effects.

Here's what I have. Fair warning: this doesn't come close to working or compiling I believe. But I do feel like maybe I want to use one of `combineLatest`, `collect`, `reduce`, etc. Just lost on what to do specifically. I do feel like this makes something easy quite hard.

```
class CandyViewModel {

    private let racPropertyBeansCount: MutableProperty<Int> = MutableProperty<Int>(0)

    lazy var racActionIncrementBeansCount: Action<AnyObject?, Int, NoError> = {
        return Action { _ in SignalProducer<Int, NoError>(value: 1)
        }
    }()

    var racCocoaIncrementBeansAction: CocoaAction

    init() {
        racCocoaIncrementBeansAction = CocoaAction.init(racActionIncrementBeansCount, input: "")
        // ???
        var sig = racPropertyBeansCount.producer.combineLatestWith(racActionIncrementBeansCount.)
    }

}

class CandyView: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var guiButtonMoreCandy: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet private var guiTextViewCandyCt: NSTextView!



}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class CandyViewModel {

    let racPropertyBeansCount = MutableProperty<Int>(0)

    let racActionIncrementBeansCount = Action<(), Int, NoError>{ _ in SignalProducer(value: 1) }

    init() {

        // reduce the value from the action to the mutableproperty
        racPropertyBeansCount <~ racActionIncrementBeansCount.values.reduce(racPropertyBeansCount.value) { $0 + $1 }

    }

}

class CandyView: NSViewController {

    // define outlets

    let viewModel = CandyViewModel()


    func bindObservers() {

        // bind the Action to the button
        guiButtonMoreCandy.addTarget(viewModel.racActionIncrementBeansCount.unsafeCocoaAction, action: CocoaAction.selector, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        // observe the producer of the mutableproperty
        viewModel.racPropertyBeansCount.producer.startWithNext {
            self.guiTextViewCandyCt.text = "\($0)"
        }

    }

}
```